# Using Ruby to authenticate to Azure (HTTP Header authentication)?

Tags: ruby, http-headers, http-authentication

Since the Google Search API has been deprecated, I'd like to use the Bing Search API (now a Windows Azure API) in my Ruby apps.

However, Azure has a strange authentication pattern where you build a query URI, paste it into a browser, pass the key into the password box of the standard HTTP authentication box, and make POST to see the results. I assume this generates a signature and passes it in the header somehow. I'd like to do the complete process in Ruby and skip the browser portion if possible.

I found **one example** in the source of an [obscure Windows Azure storage gem](https://github.com/johnnyhalife/waz-storage/blob/master/lib/waz/storage/core_service.rb), but I can't figure out how tthey're building the signature and make the call. Is there a simple way to do basic HTTP auth in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and used Faraday's built in basic authentication scheme like so:

```
connection = Faraday.new "http://api.something.com/1/dudez"
connection.basic_auth "username" "password"
connection.get
```

Comment: `basic_auth` says that it expects one argument instead of two.  Has the syntax changed?

Comment: if you need to add any custom headers, make sure you add basic_auth AFTER the headers have been set because they'll get reset by the headers method.

Answer (score 1):

I want to recommend the [RestClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) gem for this. I've used it with great success for GET'ing and POST'ing across domains. If you really have to act like a browser to implement the API, you can always use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

I'm sorry I haven't tried the Azure API myself, or I would give an example. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recall doing this previously with another Azure API but am unable to find the code.

Look here for the details of the signature process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx

I'm unable to find immediately if the Azure API uses the SharedSignature method

Answer (score 0):

The way to sign a request to Windows Azure blob storage thru the REST API is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx.

Basically, you don't authenticate by simply adding some credentials in a HTTP header, you have to sign your request with the secret key that is associated to your storage account.